# create Combobox with index - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I know that it's very simple, but I just can't find how to do it.

All I wanna do is create a combobox with index!
I'm doing this:

```
combobox.AddItem "test", 1
```

but i'm getting errors!
If I  don't put the index, it works!

How can I do it?

Sorry for the stupid question!

Comment: Change the 1 to a 0.  Combobox indexes are zero-based.

Comment: I have a table of knives with Id and Name. Can't I create a combobox with the name of knife and its Id as index?

Comment: Yes you can. Sorry, I misunderstood.  Looks like @the_barman got it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a little bit of code which may help get some understanding of combobox:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
ComboBox1.AddItem "Col-1 Item-" & ComboBox1.ListCount + 1
ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = "Col-2 Item-" & ComboBox1.ListCount
End Sub
```